# phpMyAdmin: How do I schedule my stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, mariadb

**Using:** phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.7

**Goal:** Schedule my stored procedure to run ever night (for testing purposes, I have it set to run every 1 minute)

**Problem:** I *feel* like I have it scheduled correctly, but I know it is not because part of my sproc (in testing) is to create a 'test' tbl, but I do not see the tbl being created

**What I Know:** I know the sproc is written correctly because I can manually run it, and it manually runs successfully

**What I Have Tried:** I have tried to set this up using the settings in the screenshots below

Could anyone please inform me of why my sproc is not running on schedule?

**sproc:**
[image]

**Event (Schedule):**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
`CREATE EVENT Event_Name
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2016-03-27 00:00:00'
DO CALL sproc_operations()`
```

will be the query.
Even if it doesn't insert the data in your expected test table then try calling the stored procedure manually and check whether the stored procedure have some issue.

Do check whether the user is allowed to create event or not by checking Privileges.
Refer [Checking and Granting Privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-privileges.html)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried running exactly what you wrote, minus the beginning ' and ending ' of course, but I got a syntax error, saying to make sure it is in line with the correct version of MariaDB (which is 5.5.44-MariaDB-cll-lve)

Comment: 1. Find the [manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html).  2. Find where in the statement it complained ("... near 'START ...).  3. It's easy to fix from there !

Comment: @RickJames: Yes, it should be 'STARTS' instead of 'START', i had edited my answer, but Chase has some issue related MariaDB

Comment: Yes, I will take a further look at it this weekend, as I'll have time then. I will certainly report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your Event Scheduler is off.  Turn it on as follows:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html